# Disable local authentication methods for Cosmos DB database accounts using Azure CLI

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to create a cosmos DB account using Azure CLI.
One of required policies I have to comply with is **"Cosmos DB database accounts should have local authentication methods disabled"**. In the following document I see how to set it using Azure Resource Manager templates . See below

```
"resources": [
    {
        "type": " Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts",
        "properties": {
            "disableLocalAuth": true,
            // ...
        },
        // ...
    },
    // ...
 ]
```

Now my question is how to do the same using AZ CLI?

The command I am using is => **az cosmosdb create ...**

I don't see any flag that will allow the similar setting in AZ CLI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of January 2022 this is only supported via ARM Templates but support for PS and CLI is planned. No ETA to share at this time.

Answer (score 5):

It's not supported through the `az cosmosdb` commands but you could use the `az resource update` command to update this property:

```
$cosmosdbname = "<cosmos-db-account-name>"
$resourcegroup = "<resource-group-name>"
$cosmosdb = az cosmosdb show --name $cosmosdbname --resource-group $resourcegroup | ConvertFrom-Json

az resource update --ids $cosmosdb.id --set properties.disableLocalAuth=true --latest-include-preview
```

Answer (score 2):

You can always use Azure REST API invocation to apply any change in the CosmosDB account, see here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db-resource-provider/2021-10-15/database-accounts/create-or-update

I've used Postman for that, btw I post a CURL example here by which I was able to modify a couple of properties (you need to get an oauth2 token before):

```
curl --location --request PUT 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<resource-group-name>/providers/Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/<database-account-name>?api-version=2021-10-15' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer <oauth2-token>' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "location": "North Europe",
    "properties": {
        "databaseAccountOfferType": "Standard",
        "disableLocalAuth": true,
        "disableKeyBasedMetadataWriteAccess":true,
        "locations": [
            {
                "isVirtualNetworkFilterEnabled": false,
                "locationName": "North Europe",
                "failoverPriority": 0,
                "isZoneRedundant": false
            }
        ]
    }
}'
```

Comment: thank you. I will try it out

Answer (score 1):

**No** , this is not supported through the Azure CLI when you are creating Azure Cosmos DB account via `az cosmosdb create`

Comment: So it is only possible using ARM templates or setting it manually from portal?

Comment: ARM template as of now