# Polly Policy for azure cosmos function when cosmos Authkey updated

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-keyvault, polly

I am using an azure cosmos function, which has some azure auth Key in the key vault.
The Authkey will be changed every 10 days. Whenever the auth key changed, I had to restart my function as I was receiving an error saying

> "Unauthorized (401),The input authorization token can't serve the request. The wrong key is being used or the expected payload is not built as per the protocol".

My senior collague suggested using the Polly policy to resolve this without restarting the function.

Could someone please help me to resolve this? I am not understanding where to apply the Polly policy code exactly.

My `ServiceCollectionExtenstion` class a below (where I will receive the error)

```
public static IServiceCollection AddCosmosStore<TEntity>(this IServiceCollection services,
    string databaseName, Uri endpointUri, string authKey, Action<CosmosStoreSettings> settingsAction = null,
    string overriddenContainerName = "") where TEntity : class
{
    var settings = new CosmosStoreSettings(databaseName, endpointUri, authKey);
    settingsAction?.Invoke(settings);
    return services.AddCosmosStore<TEntity>(settings, overriddenContainerName);
}

public static IServiceCollection AddCosmosStore<TEntity>(this IServiceCollection services, CosmosStoreSettings settings, string overriddenContainerName = "") where TEntity : class
{
    services.AddSingleton<ICosmosStore<TEntity>>(x => new CosmosStore<TEntity>(settings, overriddenContainerName)); // error comes from here
    return services;
}
```

[image: Error message as below]

This can be resolved if I restart the function, but want to make it happen automatically

Thanks.

Comment: could you share the implementation of yuour cosmosstore class ?

Comment: also if you plan to rotate key every 10days, you probably wanna try using azure ad auth and disable auth key ?

Comment: Hi Thomas, Sorry for the delay in response. Could you please  me with any links/reference-Url to check in this way ?

Comment: main documentation about rbac: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/secure-access-to-data?tabs=using-primary-key#rbac

Comment: this SO post will explain ho0w to disable access key: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70849701/disable-local-authentication-methods-for-cosmos-db-database-accounts-using-azure

Comment: HI Thomas, I have seen the referred links provided by disabling the key but I have to use Polly policy to achieve this as the functions were working whenever I am restarting them once after the key updated.

Comment: if you disable keys, you dont need polly policy. it is a different approach for sure because it does not relay on keys but on Azure AD auth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a retry policy like this:

```
var refreshAuthKeyPolicy = Policy
    .Handle<CosmosException>(ex => ex.StatusCode == (HttpStatusCode)401)
    .Retry(1, (response, retryCount) =>
    {
        //refresh authKey
        settings.AuthKey = newAuthKey;
    }
);
```

- `.Handle<CosmosException>(ex => ex.StatusCode == (HttpStatusCode)401)`: triggers whenever you receive an `Unauthorized` response
- `//refresh authKey`: retrieves the new credentials
- `.Retry(1`: performs again the component registration

You should decorate the `AddCosmosStore` method like this:

```
var settings = new CosmosStoreSettings(databaseName, endpointUri, authKey);
settingsAction?.Invoke(settings);

var refreshAuthKeyPolicy = Policy
    .Handle<CosmosException>(ex => ex.StatusCode == (HttpStatusCode)401)
    .Retry(1, (response, retryCount) =>
    {
        //refresh authKey
        settings.AuthKey = newAuthKey;
    }
);

refreshAuthKeyPolicy.Execute(() => services.AddCosmosStore<TEntity>(settings, overriddenContainerName));
return services;
```

Comment: Hi Peter, Thanks for the reply. My authkey stored in key-vault. So the above code may not work in this. Is there any alternative way to achieve this ?

Comment: Hi @Naurtosan why is it a problem? Can't you retrieve the new auth key through a keyvault API call?

Comment: Hi @Naurtosan, I have seen that you have left some comments yesterday (or the day before yesterday) but now they are gone. Did you succeed or do you need some help?

Comment: Hi @Peter, Sorry for the delay in response. I have applied the changes but observed that the policy code calling does not happen when the 401 error occurs, I am verifying that and let you know.

Comment: I am seeing the below error,{"messageResponses":[{"Action":1,"MessageId":"123456-0e34-4196-aa71-32cee468751f","Reason":"Error constructing handler for request of type MediatR.IRequestHandler`2[Strand.Ingestor.EventSubscriber.Infrastructure.Commands.Models.SkillUpdateCommand,System.Boolean]. Register your handlers with the container. See the samples in GitHub for examples.","PublishMessages":{"Messages":null,"RequestId":"123ccccc-5cb3-4460-b001-cfeebbca76bf"}}]}, But if I am correct there is no need to register any handler as we are not adding any new hanlder

Comment: @Naurtosan Well it is hard to say anything about the problem here. You have shared with us only some DI registrations and an exception. Now it seemly (based on the error reason) that you are using MediatR.

Comment: Yes, Peter, the error is different but there is something that that retry method is not calling again when an issue comes i.e., to update the key the method has not been calling again.

Comment: @Naurtosan It is not being called because in the policy it is explicitly defined that perform a retry only if the exception's `StatusCode` is 401. If you receive a different status code then it will not be triggered. Does it make sense?

Comment: No peter, even for 401 error it is not calling, I am looking in to it, i will post you once it got resolved

Comment: @Naurtosan Did you add a breakpoint inside the `.Handle<CosmosException>(` 's delegate? Was it called and was the status code 401?

Comment: Hi Peter, I have achieved the request. Thanks for the help. Keep Helping :)

Comment: Hi @Naurtosan, I'm glad to read. Could you please with the community how did you solve your problem?